# Alternative approach to pthread_cancel with asynchronous termination

Tags: c++, linux, asynchronous, pthreads, fork

I understood that using `pthread_cancel` to cancel a thread asynchronously with `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHROUNOUS` is only applicable for purely computational and not suitable for complicated functions. If we use `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED`, this does not guarantee it can be completed if the function contains no `pthread` cancellation points especially calling third-party libraries.

1) I saw some suggestions using interprocess communication that `fork` a child process and `kill` it when timeout occurs.

2) There are also comments that we should use `pthread_create` with a shared variable to break out / exit the loop gracefully and perform cleanup. I am not quite sure how should I implement this if the function itself is a long blocking call (e.g. take few seconds).

Which approach is better and how should I implement it? Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Do you know about pthread_kill?

Comment: @jimmcnamara: Do you mean using `pthread_kill(thread, 0)` for error checking against ESRCH, or send a signal to the thread?

Comment: You can signal the thread with maybe SIGUSR1.  But.  You have to be sure (probably a mutex) that you synchronize the thread to be sure it has run your thread's signal handler function.  Before assuming you can send a signal.  This means the signal handler has to determine whether or not it can exit. pthread_cond_wait can help here.

Comment: @jimmcnamara: Please can you kindly explain a little bit more (or some examples will be great) and put it as an answer as I am still learning how to use `pthread`? I am calling a third party library in the thread function which could take up to few seconds to complete a function call. If I want to stop it asynchronously when it takes more than 1 second, how should I make use of `pthread_kill` and signal handler? Many thanks!

Comment: Try this first - pthread_kill is not usually a good choice.   I thought you had some esoteric sempahore/mutex lock problem or something.  https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarSignal   This shows how to code condition variables.  Which it now seems like you want.

Comment: @jimmcnamara: If count++ takes 10 seconds to complete in the example, it will not signal the watch thread within 1 second. I want to either (1) cancel the count thread after 1 second, or (2) somehow monitor if the count thread is exited in the watch thread before joining the count thread (because I do not want to block the watch thread permanently using `pthread_join` if possible). According to what you said, I believe case (2) is a better solution but I have no idea how to implement this. Do you have a better example on case (2)?